# javascript regex match words with backslash

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I am trying get directory name with backslash, but I am getting this
DirectoryFolder. Can't figure out how to match backslah \ as well.

```
DirPath = "Directory\Folder"

val = DirPath.match(/(\w+)/)[1];
```

The result I want is this

Directory\Folder

Comment: Could you give us some more input of what should and what should not match?

Comment: it should match "Directory\Folder". I am extracting this info a text file. The test might look like this. "This is your home folder Directory\Folder....

Comment: The string should be `var DirPath = "Directory\\Folder"`, otherwise the ``\`` will be left out, missing, in the string. Then, `DirPath.match(/\w+/)[0]` will work.

Answer (score 0):

My regex isn't the best but this might work.

```
([A-Z\\])\w+
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to know how to match a backslash, correct?

If that is the case, you can escape your backslash

The final regex would look like `/(\w|\\)+/`

Comment: Correct, I tried your code. Still don't work. It return data without backslash. DirectoryFolder, but I want it to return Directory\Folder

Comment: @azadaawaraa , when I run your code, it looks like the \ in DirPath is trying to escape the `F` in Folder.  When I change it to `DirPath = "Directory\\Folder";` it matches. Are you defining DirPath manually, or are you getting it from somewhere already defined?

Comment: I am getting it from other place. So, I cannot  change it to "Directory\\Folder". It has to stay as "Directory\Folder". I am extracting the "Directory\Folder" from string of text file.

Comment: Can you post how you are getting it from the text file?  And how is that text file being populated?  Is it possible that the \ isn't being escaped before it is stored to the text file?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use ES6? If so you can use the [`String.raw()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) static method:

```js
var DirPath = String.raw`Directory\Folder`;

var re = /[\w\\]+/;

document.body.textContent = DirPath.match(re);
```